# How to install packages from github

Tags: ros, nav-msgs, github, rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I know how to clone a repository from github, but that's all. I would like to install the common_msgs collection of packages onto my Raspberry Pi which is running debian jessie.  How do I go about installing ROS packages, or a collection of ROS packages from github?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240235/how-to-install-packages-from-github/) by [Raisintoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27360/raisintoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-07-23

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you have a catkin workspace set up already. If not you can follow [this](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). Once that is done, you can go to the github page for your package. In this case, I believe you are looking for [common_msgs](https://github.com/ros/common_msgs).

Open terminal and navigate to src folder in your catkin workspace:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
```

Then clone the repository using:

```
git clone -b <branch> <address>
```

For example, if you are looking to run it in `ros hydro`, your command could look like:

```
 git clone -b hydro-devel https://github.com/ros/common_msgs.git
```

Once it is completed, do the following:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws 
catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) with karma: 178 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-02-08**:
I am using ros indigo and I followed ur steps but I am getting error : 'fatal: Remote branch indigo-devel not found in upstream origin'

Please help @skr_robo

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2017-02-08**:
In some cases, they may not have specific branch set up for your version of ROS. What I have posted here is only one possible example. Go to git and see what branches they have. If they haven't said anything about using a specific branch for indigo, the master branch should probably work.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2017-02-08**:
If you still couldn't get it done, please post the git link here. Also, note that indigo-devel is only indigo development branch. It may not always be a good idea to use it. I strongly recommend you try:

```
git clone <address>
```

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-02-09**:
Thanks for your reply @skr_robo

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-02-09**:
This time I got [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S9nxkjWZQ5by8pPtwfbTs-8HjPKkcpiBT150aNbb6qk) error in the final step while doing catkin_make

[Here](https://github.com/kbogert/cmvision.git) is the link of github that has the package I want to install.

**Comment by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on 2017-02-09**:
Finally I was able to execute catkin_make successfully. I figured out that I was missing a package called wxWidgets. On installing this package everything worked well

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [Installing ROS from source tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source). One of the notes for example states how to change the install target for catkin_make:

> Note: The default catkin installation location would be ~/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated, if you would like to install some where else then you can do this by adding the --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic argument to your catkin_make_isolated call.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2016-07-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gb96](https://answers.ros.org/users/35452/gb96/) on 2018-05-25**:
I wanted to install a new package this way, however my user login does not have write privilege to /opt/ros/

When I tried using sudo, that didn't work either because root did not have the necessary environment from setup.bash

Managed to do it via a root shell (using sudo -s) but was awkward.

**Comment by [Beshari](https://answers.ros.org/users/38636/beshari/) on 2019-10-07**:
Thank you, was exactly looking for that